# how to display a numeric value if certain height is reached in a block?(Using jQuery)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have following snippet of html and css

```
<div class="tags">
  <p>tag1</p>
  <p>tag2</p>
  <p>tag</p>
  <p>tag4</p>
  <p>tag5</p>
</div>
```

```
:root {
  --lh: 1.5rem;
  --max-lines: 3;
}
.tags {
  max-height: calc(var(--lh) * var(--max-lines));
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tags p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

So, here the height of the ***tags*** is limited to 3 lines by setting the ***max-height** and any content overflown will be hidden.

Here, I want to display the overflown tags as +1 if one tag is overflown and +2 if two are overflown and so on. For this I could create a span tag and set the text of it to the number but how could I calculate how many tags are overflown.

How could I achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: I think jQuery's :visible might do the trick, but i can't seem to replicate the max 3 lines part so i can't test if my idea works

Comment: So, @Ramon deVries, Can I take the count of the visible and hidden elements?

Answer (score 0):

This entire task can easily be handled with jQuery. First hide all the tags then show each up to the limit. Below I added a `data-limit` attribute to the container allowing multiple instances of `.tags` to each have their own limit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tags').each(function() {
    let $bag = $(this)
    let $tags = $bag.find('p')
    let limit = parseInt($bag.data('limit'))
    let over = $tags.length - limit
    $tags.hide();
    if (over) {
      $('<p>+' + over + '</p>').appendTo($bag)
    }
    $tags.each(function(index, tag) {
      if (index < limit) {
        $(tag).show()
      } else {
        return false
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.tags {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags" data-limit="3">
  <p>tag1</p>
  <p>tag2</p>
  <p>tag</p>
  <p>tag4</p>
  <p>tag5</p>
</div>
<div class="tags" data-limit="2">
  <p>tag1</p>
  <p>tag2</p>
  <p>tag</p>
  <p>tag4</p>
  <p>tag5</p>
</div>
<div class="tags" data-limit="3">
  <p>tag1</p>
  <p>tag2</p>
  <p>tag</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution you have giver looks similar but I only have a single div with multiple tags in it. And the tags are displayed as flex items. So I used ***overflow:hidden***. Will data-limit work here?

Comment: @Gowthamss Yes, I just try to use a portable solution whenever possible. You can always hard code `limit` and omit `data-limit`